# Creating a simple theme and child theme in another color

Tags: wordpress

Hello I'm sorry for the question but as I'm .net programmer and have never worked with wordpress I hope I will have some help here with these two tasks:

1. Find (or create) an easy to edit web template/theme 
   http://www.freecsstemplates.org/preview/angledtheme/
2. Create a child theme in another base color and change post titles to be green.

So I would be very glad if someone can tell me the important aspects of the tasks - I mean what is important in this template to follow and maybe some instructions and guidance how can I achieve this and something to read.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to develop the base theme to keep the structure of your html template in mind. And this tutorial( http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial ) helps you a lot to develop the base theme.

After your base theme you have to develop the child theme, take a look on this (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Some points to keep in mind:

1. Digg some research on functions.php file and read about the value of this file.
2. Some basic research on wordpress hooks and filters
3. Most Important first coverup the **basic of PHP** as you said in your question *"I'm .net programmer "*